# Index names get a number appended

Tags: azure-search

I switched from Solr to Azure search and followed all the steps listed in the [blog](http://www.integryx.net/post/2019/01/05/switch-sitecore-9-from-solr-to-azure-search-step-by-step-instructions).
I Also renamed the Solr core to lower case with dashes. 
When I run the `xConnectSearchIndexer -rr` service the indexes are created in the Azure but the names are different.

The master index name is `sitecore-master-index-732` instead of just `sitecore-master-index`.

Is there some configuration/step that I have set incorrectly or missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal behaviour in Sitecore 9.1+ and is not a problem.
You have [Sitecore Azure Search switch on rebuild](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/zero-downtime-index-rebuild-in-azure-search.html) enabled, so it will append a random number to the index name when rebuilding and then switch to using it once the rebuild is complete. It should then delete the old index.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Mark